# Spring cloud keystore example doesn't work

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to get a keystore working to back the encryption capability of Spring Cloud Configuration Server.  STS gives an error and encrypt/status continues to complain.   I get an error in my application.yml file

```
server:
    port: 8888
spring:
    cloud:
      config:
        server:
          git:
            uri: ${GIT_CONFIG_URI}
            username: ${GIT_USERNAME}
            password: ${GIT_PASSWORD}
          encrypt:
            keyStore:
              location: ${ENCRYPT_KEY_STORE_URL}
              password: ${ENCRYPT_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD}
              alias: ${ENCRYPT_KEY_STORE_ALIAS}
              secret: ${ENCRYPT_KEY_STORE_SECRET}
```

IN STS:     **Unknown property 'spring.cloud.config.server.encrypt.keyStore'**

The verbatim example from the documentation http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.3.1.RELEASE/#_security

```
encrypt:
  keyStore:
    location: classpath:/server.jks
    password: letmein
    alias: mytestkey
    secret: changeme
```

Comment: An unknown property in STS just means it doesn't have that in its metadata, doesn't mean it won't work. What is the runtime error?

Comment: There's no stacktrace or anythign like that on startup. The <host>/<context>/encrypt/status page says no key is installed

Unless I am missing something,  Encrypt is a static nested class and only has the attribute that STS is showing -- enabled or disabled.   

[https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/ConfigServerProperties.java

Comment: Definitely there is a doc defect at minimum.  It's clearly referred elsewhere as **"key-store"**,   e.g.  @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "encrypt.key-store.location", matchIfMissing = false)   [https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EncryptionAutoConfiguration.java

Comment: what version are you using? I've made fixes to make sure the relaxed binding worked on those properties (ie: keyStore vs key-store).

Comment: Originally I had 1.1.2.RELEASE but after the problems I pulled in 1.3.2-RELEASE.   Unfortunately I am going to have to punt on keystores for the release I am working on and go with a symmetric key.   I really would like to figure this out though since the asymmetric seems like the right way to go down the road.

Comment: You should be using the spring cloud dependency BOM, otherwise you might have mismatched versions